# How to apply limits to integration?

Tags: calculus

http://papers.xtremepapers.com/CIE/Cambridge%20International%20A%20and%20AS%20Level/Mathematics%20(9709)/9709_s12_qp_11.pdf

On this exam paper, question 11, ii, iii, 
marking scheme: http://papers.xtremepapers.com/CIE/Cambridge%20International%20A%20and%20AS%20Level/Mathematics%20(9709)/9709_s12_ms_11.pdf

It says, 'Apply limits 1 and their 2 ‘correctly’'
How do I know what limits to use, when it's not given?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what they mean by "their 2", but you are trying to find the values of $y$ that bound that [region](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=area+between+y%3D2%2Fsqrt(x%2B1)+and+y%3D1+from+x%3D0+to+x%3D3). They give you in the guidelines that $y=2$ (this can also be seen by plugging in to find the value of $y$ at $x=0$) is the upper bound and you can see from the graph that region ends at $y=1$. They obtain the expressions they show as answers by plugging these values into the antiderivative.

Comment: Thank you, so everytime I need to find the area, and I don't have limits, I have to find the lowest/highest points of the shaded region and use those as a limit? Or that can't be used everytime?

Comment: If you have a bounded region you want to find the area, you want to find the antiderivative at the boundaries. Lowest and highest might not be the best descriptors in general.